# how to http:post file with httpc:request in erlang?

Tags: http, post, erlang

I used to code like this :

```
inets:start(),
ssl:start(),
ParaUrl = io_lib:format("http://xxx/passport?accessn=~s",[Access]),
ParaStr = io_lib:format("id=~p",[Id]),
RegUsr = httpc:request(post,{ParaUrl, [],"application/x-www-form-urlencoded", list_to_binary(ParaStr)},[],[])
```

but it's just for string not binary file, can anyone tell me how to post binary file with httpc:request?

Comment: You want to send the contents of a file?

Comment: yeah , like picture ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by [ActiveState recipe 146306](https://github.com/ActiveState/code/blob/master/recipes/Python/146306_Http_client_POST_using/recipe-146306.py) (and [PYTHON HTTP POST BINARY FILE UPLOAD WITH PYCURL (PYTHON RECIPE)](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/576422-python-http-post-binary-file-upload-with-pycurl/)), altered by [Formatting Multipart Formdata in Erlang](https://lethain.com/formatting-multipart-formdata-in-erlang/). Thanks!

```
format_multipart_formdata(Boundary, Fields, Files) ->
    FieldParts = lists:map(fun({FieldName, FieldContent}) ->
        [lists:concat(["--", Boundary]),
            lists:concat(["Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"",atom_to_list(FieldName),"\""]),
            "", FieldContent]
                           end, Fields),

    FieldParts2 = lists:append(FieldParts),


    FileParts = lists:map(fun({FieldName, FileName, FileContent}) ->

        [lists:concat(["--", Boundary]),
            lists:concat(["Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"",atom_to_list(FieldName),"\"; filename=\"",FileName,"\""]),
            lists:concat(["Content-Type: ", "application/octet-stream"]), "", FileContent]
                          end, Files),
    FileParts2 = lists:append(FileParts),
    EndingParts = [lists:concat(["--", Boundary, "--"]), ""],
    Parts = lists:append([FieldParts2, FileParts2, EndingParts]),
    string:join(Parts, "\r\n").
```

Usage:

```
{ok,BinStream} = file:read_file("./images/avatar.png"),
Data = binary_to_list(BinStream), 
Boundary = "------WebKitFormBoundaryUscTgwn7KiuepIr1",
ReqBody = format_multipart_formdata(Boundary, [{uid,"123"}], [{avatar, "avatar", Data}]),
ContentType = lists:concat(["multipart/form-data; boundary=", Boundary]),
ReqHeader = [{"Content-Length", integer_to_list(length(ReqBody))}],

inets:start(),
ParaUrl = string:join(["http://www.example.com/avatar?access_token=",binary_to_list(token)],""),
RegUsr = httpc:request(post,{ParaUrl, ReqHeader,ContentType, ReqBody},[],[])
```

Answer (score 3):

It works for me:

```
 {ok, F} = file:read_file("warning.gif"),
    httpc:request(post,{Url, [],"multipart/form-data", F},[],[]).
```

I recieved on cowboy web server with function `cowboy_req:body(Req)`:

```
{ok,<<71,73,70,56,57,97,11,0,11,0,230,64,0............>>,
     {http_req,#Port<0.65562>,ranch_tcp,keepalive,<0.8736.0>,<<"POST">>,
               'HTTP/1.1',
               {{127,0,0,1},58154},
               <<"localhost">>,undefined,8000,<<"/test1">>,
               [<<"test1">>],
               <<>>,undefined,[],
               [{<<"content-type">>,<<"multipart/form-data">>},
                {<<"content-length">>,<<"516">>},
                {<<"te">>,<<>>},
                {<<"host">>,<<"localhost:8000">>},
                {<<"connection">>,<<"keep-alive">>}],
               [{<<"content-length">>,516},
                {<<"expect">>,undefined},
                {<<"content-length">>,516},
                {<<"connection">>,[<<"keep-alive">>]}],undefined,[],done,undefined,<<>>,true,waiting,[],<<>>,
               undefined}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ,  and I also figured out an answer blow , you can read it ...